# How do I prevent these errors from showing up with GNOME keyring?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, xfce, git

## Background

Trying to update a repository, after a fresh install of Xubuntu 12.04, using:

```
git pull
```

## Problem

The following message appeared:

```
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-*****/pkcs11
```

## Question

How do you prevent the message from showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this message](http://laslow.net/2012/05/06/gnome-keyring-issues-in-ubuntu-12-04/):

1. Edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop`.
2. Find: `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity`
3. Append `;XFCE` as follows: `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;XFCE`
4. Restart X.

Problem solved.